# Is it necessary to store a value from a method which is returning a value in java?

Tags: java

Let suppose I have a method

```
public int dummy(){
  return 1;
}
```

and if I call this method by

```
dummy();
```

not

```
int a  = dummy();
```

will it make any difference? why?

Comment: "*will it make any difference?*" - Yes. --- "*why?*" - If the return value is not stored, no stack memory is allocated on the calling side.

Comment: If you don't want the value returned by the method, what would be the purpose of calling `dummy()`?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference in results. It's a common practice to ignore values returned from functions like `List.remove`, `Map.put` etc.

Comment: "*Is it necessary to store...*" if you don't need it, you do not need to store it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it wouldn't make any difference. We call a ton of methods from the JDK ignoring their outputs - List's `.remove(int index)` removes the element at a given index, and returns what element was removed. It is normal to ignore it and move ahead.

Answer (score 4):

It will still compile, but (assuming that the method is just called in isolation) it'll be pointless, since you can never use the value returned. (At a deeper level, and depending on implementation, it's possible the JVM may optimise away the method call entirely.)

If however you do `int a  = dummy();`, then you can later reference that variable, eg. `System.out.println(a);` will print out its value.

If your method had another side effect other than returning a value, such as:

```
public int dummy(){
    System.out.println("hello");
    return 1;
}
```

...then calling it without assigning its result to a variable wouldn't be pointless, since the side effect would still occur (printing "hello" in this case). While some argue this is poor design, this sometimes occurs in practice in the Java libraries - you could call `createnewFile()` on a `File` object for instance and ignore its returned boolean value (which will tell you whether the file was created or not.)

Comment: I think the JIT almost certainly will optimize away a call like this.  However if the code is still being interpreted then probably not, so the statement is more like "the JVM may optimize away this call" rather than the JIT (which is pretty much a sure thing).

Answer (score 1):

These two are both true statements, but the difference is, when you use

```
dummy()
```

this will call the function in the program, but since you are returning a value, it is pointless ( considering you will keep the value )

When you use

```
int a = dummy()
```

You will create an integer named a in order to store the output ( return value ) of the function, which you can reuse any time.